# What can we know about undiscovered proofs?

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification

What can we know about undiscovered proofs?

Please note that my knowledge of maths extends to simple calculus. In real life I have only ever had to use arithmetic and a little algebra. Please excuse any deficiencies on my part.

I would like to get to grips with what a mathematician can know about undiscovered proofs. To make myself clear I'll cite some examples with my proposed logic.

1. If no-one has found a proof for proposition pX and someone who does not know the proof can prove that there must be a proof, then they have actually proved pX
2. If someone can prove there must be a couterexample to pX even though no-one can find that counterexample then they they have disproved pX
3. It is possible to prove something about the range of pX even if the general solution of pX is not known. For example by exhaustive search up to a certain limit we can show the *if* a counterexample exists then the counterexample must exist outside the searched range.

If the above logic is correct then I would like to open things up by considering what sort of things can be known about an undiscovered proof.

**Example**

If we stringently define the mathematics that we believe Fermat to have known. Can we perhaps *prove* that it was impossible for him to have proved his famous Last Theorem using only those methods. Or indeed prove that it would have been possible even though we don't know how he actually did it.

**Question**

Is there a generally accepted term for this? I thought of meta-proof but can only find joke references.

If such a discipline exists, what can we say about the parameters of a proof that can be known short of finding an actual proof?

Comment: "What can we know about undiscovered proofs?" Nothing.  You example regarding Fermat's "lost" proof is relevant: centuries were needed before someone found Fermat's Last Th proof and there is **no** reason at all to assume that it was the proof Fermat alluded to. It is reasonable that Fermat had no valid proof at all, maybe a conjecture...

Comment: How can someone prove that there must be a proof? Either there is a proof of a theorem, or proof there is not one.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA  - I think you have misunderstood.  You say, *It is reasonable that Fermat had no valid proof at all*.  It may be reasonable. I am asking whether it can be shown to be *impossible*, or indeed *possible* ***Without knowing what it was*** within the system of mathematics of the time.

Comment: This question is quite trivial ... :-) "Can we prove that it was impossible for him to have proved his famous LT ?" Of course yes: providing a counter-example.

Comment: But the "historically interesting" fact is exactly this: without a proof, we had no reason to believe in a purported theorem, but for about four centuries no one was able to find a counter-example.

Comment: Maybe this question is somewhat like "are there techniques to show that a proof must exist for a proposition, and yet nobody has constructed a proof?"  That, I don't know... I guess we need a logician.  Previously I would have said that proofs were by nature constructed things, and you couldn't talk about a provable statement without a proof.  Sort of like "out of all statements that are true in a logical system, provable things are the constructively true statements."  Perhaps I am abusing the term "constructive" but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA - I would prefer that you read my question carefully rather than joke about it. Wiles showed there is no counter-example. My question is about what can be proved within a particular *system* of maths.

Comment: See [Proof of impossibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_impossibility): is a "technique" quite recent.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA  - Thanks. That looks like an interesting read.

Comment: Your case 1 seems to be in fact a proof. Look up "non-constructive proofs" for examples of your case 2. Another interesting case is "zero knowledge proofs", where you prove that you have a proof to a statement without disclosing the proof itself.

Comment: Your question seems similar to "what can we know about unsolved problems (in mathematics)?" Although there are many unsolved problems currently, we can prove that if a solution exists, it must follow a set of criteria. For example, it is currently unknown whether there are any odd perfect numbers, but we do know if one exists, it must be greater than $10^{1500}$ and must not be divisible by $105$. Very frequently there is a significant breakthrough before a proof is discovered, and the final proof often combines existing knowledge with some other new technique that ties everything together.

Comment: If you would like to refine your question to discuss further about unsolved problems in mathematics, please let me know.

Comment: @Toby Mak - Yes that is indeed one part of what am asking. I realise now from the comments that I unwittingly combined two questions into one. As no-one has formally answered, perhaps I should delete this and reformulate it as two separate questions (or possibly three)

Comment: @Toby Mak - Thank you for your kind offer I will reformulate a question as you suggest then, if you are agreeable, I'll ask you to vet it before I submit.

Comment: If Fermat's last theorem would have turned out to be false, we could of course prove that he could not prove it, but since it turned out to be true, we can just be very sure that he could not have proven it.

Comment: @Peter - Very sure, maybe. But can we conceivably be *certain* that he could not have? (given the tools available at the time)

Comment: To proof the existence of a counterexample is enough for a refutation, it is not necessary that it is feasible to find it. Since Goedel we know that a true statement need not be provable within the theory we are working with. So , we cannot just argue that "there must be a proof". This is like saying : "I am right because I say that I am right".

Comment: @Peter -  Yes that is exactly one of the things I am wondering about. I shall have to read about Goedel  - thanks.

Comment: Noone knows whether there is a proof of Fermat's last theorem with tools that were available at that time. But what makes me (and most mathematicians) secptical is that he claimed to have an EASY proof , but who knows what he called "easy" and who knows whether he had the idea of the tools later used ? Noone knows. That said, I am pretty sure that he was victim of a fake-proof. Can happen to everyone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110407/discussion-between-peter-and-chasly-from-uk).